# how to raise event on user authentication end in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I use asp.net MVC.
I need to know when a user is logging off, in order to write to data base

So- Is there an event for the authentication_end, such as the event session_end in global.asax file ?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you use for Authentication?

Answer (score 0):

you can use cookies for session management.
FormsAuthentication For 
and in global.asax
use following event.
 public void FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(object sender, FormsAuthenticationEventArgs args)